# Запрет 3 пробелов подряд

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, angular4

Плохо знаю регулярные выражения. 
У меня есть форма в Angular 5, для полей есть различные способы валидации, один из них Validators.pattern который добавляет шаблон в виде регулярного выражения, в данном случае мне нужен шаблон для ввода любого количества слов, но количество пробелов не больше 3
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Можете без регулярки найти подстроку состоящую из трех пробелов. Если она есть, то все плохо ;)

Comment: Регулярка ничего не запрещает - тупо не её это дело. Она либо проверяет на соответствие шаблону, либо преобразует в соответствии с шаблоном. Всё. Что-то запрещать может лишь внешний код на основании соответствия регулярке. Но в данном конкретном случае решение от @Visman попроще будет...

Comment: Ладно, распишу задачу подробнее, у меня есть форма в Angular 5, для полей есть различные способы валидации, один из них Validators.pattern который добавляет, как выразились выше шаблон, в данном случае мне нужен шаблон для ввода любого количества слов, но количество пробелов не больше 3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Не более трёх пробелов на весь текст:

```
^(\S*\s){0,3}\S*$
```

Проверка:

```css
input { box-sizing: border-box; width: 100%; border: 1px solid; outline: none; }
:valid { border-color: green; }
:invalid { border-color: red; }
```

```html
<input pattern="^(\S*\s){0,3}\S*$" autofocus>
```

## Не более трёх пробелов подряд:

```
^((?!\s{4}).)*$
```

Проверка:

```css
input { box-sizing: border-box; width: 100%; border: 1px solid; outline: none; }
:valid { border-color: green; }
:invalid { border-color: red; }
```

```html
<input pattern="^((?!\s{4}).)*$" autofocus>
```

Comment: Наглядно и доступно ))) +1

Comment: Спасибо большое!!!!

Comment: Нашёл небольшую недоработку, важное условие это 3 пробела ПОДРЯД, при наличии 5 слов - 5 пробелов, срабатывает валидация

Comment: @Kirill, готово.

Comment: Класс, спасибо!!!!!!!

Comment: @Kirill, тогда прими ответ нажатием на галочку слева от него.